# Wordpress news like event slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I want do something like that - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsDpR.jpg

I have only function to show 6 posts, but i don't know how do it with content show like a photo.

```
function six_images_slider() {
    $args = array('numberposts' => 18, 'category'  => 22);
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    $i = 1;
    $output = '<div class="slide">';
    foreach ($recent_posts as $post) {
        $featured_permalink = get_permalink($post['ID']);
        $featured_title = get_the_title($post['ID']);
        $featured_date = get_the_time('d.m.Y');
        $featured_image_src = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post['ID'] ) );
        if ($i == 1) {
            $output .= '<div class="col-6  border-l-r">
                        <big class="white">30</big>
                        <br /><span class="font-m cream">SIERPIEŃ</span>
                    </div>';
        }
        $output .= '';
        if ($i == 6) {
            $output .= ' </div>';
            $i = 0;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
    echo $output;
}
```

I using slick slider to slide next news and more
This is code to whole page:

```
<section id="wydarzenia" class="page">
    <h2>O nas</h2>
    <h1>Na Lato Day & Night</h1>
    <p>content hover news</p>
    <article>

        <?php six_image_slider(); ?>

    </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the link you shared have taken a very different and efficient route. If you look closely, on pressing the next button, the url changes and it takes a sec to load the new page. This means, its not using an image slider and every post has its own comments and description. I dont think its built on wordpress, but if you want to make something like this wordpress, then its much simpler then you expect. 
The wordpress way of doing something like this would be as follows.

You need to create a custom post type, and call it something like gallery. Now every post in that gallery will have content area where you can add the images and details about the images, and it will have comments related to that post. Now you can also create categories inside the gallery, and every post will be linked to a gallery. Now when you view a post it will have a next button which will link to the next post from the same category. **This way its much more effecient, managable and much much faster :)**

Comment: you can do that with functions like update_post_meta and delete_post_meta. Then you can fetch the post meta by function get_post_meta. You can also use plugins like advance custom fields where you can update and delete the post metas from within the post editor.